# iPhone 5s from Dennmark to Portugal

Tags: iphone, sim

Will an unlocked iPhone 5s from Dennmark work in Portugal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an unlocked iPhone is a phone that is purchased without a service contract to a major cell phone service provider. This means that you can use an unlocked iPhone with any carrier in any country you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've visited both countries (and most other European countries) with my iPhone 5s A1530 model (=Asian version) and it works fine.  I worked both with my common simcard as wel as local simcards.  Never had any problem.

That being said, I also never had any problems using European, Asian and Australian versions of the iPhone 4, 4s, 5 and 6.

Although I don't have experience with these, I assume only with phones designed especially for US and China you might have issues in Europe.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the model number as printed on the back of the phone, it starts with the letter A and is followed by 4 digits.

The use [this](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/) table on the apple website to determine carrier compatibility. (Note: the iPhone 5s section on that page requires scrolling down quite a bit.)

Comment: The table only determines if the 4G(LTE) compatibility, even if it's not in that table he could still use 3G. It doesn't mean that the iPhone will not work on a certain carrier.